# Is a function-returned temporary object not always r-value?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, temporary-objects

```
struct Test
{
    Test()
    {}

    Test(const Test& other)
    {
        cout << "Copy" << endl;
    }

    Test(Test&& other)  
    {
        cout << "Move" << endl;
    }
};

Test* f()
{
    static Test t;
    return &t;
}

int main()
{   
    auto t = *f();
    return 0;
}
```

Output is: **Copy**

`*f()` is obviously an anonymous temporary object so that it should be an r-value and the move-constructor should be called. Why does the compiler treat `*f()` as an l-value?

Is it a bug of the compiler, or my understanding wrong?

Comment: "*`*f()` is obviously an anonymous temporary object so that it should be an r-value*" No it isn't; your assumptions are flawed.

Comment: `*f()` isn't even an object, it's a reference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The result of `f()` is an anonymous temporary object of type `Test*`. [`f()` is an rvalue](http://ideone.com/1GUiz).

`*f()` performs indirection through said pointer. As is always the case when using the indirection operator, the result is an lvalue.

Comment: The result of `f()` is a *value* of type `Test*`, not a temporary object. Scalar temporaries are extremely seldom in C++; the only place I've encountered them is passing `42` to a function with a `const int&` parameter.

Answer (score 8):

> Why does the compiler treat *f() as an l-value?

Because it *is* an l-value. The result of operator* when applied to a pointer is *always* an l-value. And you cannot implicitly move from an l-value.

Remember the golden rule with movement: movement can only happen if it is *guaranteed* to be safe (for a certain definition of "guaranteed").

Look at your code. Is it obvious that the object that you want to move from is going to be destroyed and is inaccessible after the move? If not, then you *must* use `std::move` to move from it; this tells the system that you are taking responsibility for any screw-ups that happen because of movement.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the return of `f()` is a pointer.  Dereferencing a pointer does not cause a new object to spring into existence.  However, you are copying whatever happens to be at the memory address that the return value points to into `t`.  I would certainly expect a copy in this case.

Answer (score 1):

"*f() is obviously an anonymous temporary object..."

No it's not!  It's a static object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Test f()
{
    return Test();
}

int main()
{   
    auto t = f();
    return 0;
}
```

*Now* you're returning an anonymous temporary - the clue is creating a temporary and returning it by value without binding it to name.

What you're doing, as everyone else correctly noted, is returning a pointer to a static (so non-temporary) named (so not anonymous) object.  The *pointer* may be an anonymous temporary, but the thing it points *to* is not.